# using information_schema to find size of innodb databases

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema

We have about 60-70 databases on an RDS server, and a lot of them can be deleted.

I want to do a benchmark of size before and after, and they are all (to my knowledge) innoDB tables.

So, I'm using the `information_schema` table per this link: https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/03/17/researching-your-mysql-table-sizes/
and this is great, except the first query listed (and I presume the others) just runs and runs and eventually finishes after **EIGHT MINUTES**.

I can run this query instantly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES;
```

And get about 12,500 tables.

I also notice - ironically enough - that information_schema.TABLES has no indexes!  My instinct is not to mess with that.

My best option at this point is to dump the TABLES table, and run the query on a copy that I actually index.

My questions are:
1. how dynamic is the information_schema.TABLES table and in fact that entire database
2. why is it running so slow?
3. would it be advisable to index some key fields to optimize the queries I want to do?
4. If I do do an SQL dump, will I be getting current table size information?

Thanks, I hope this question is instructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`information_schema` is currently a thin layer on top of some older stuff.  The older stuff needed to "open" each table to discover its size, etc.  That involved reading at least the `.frm`.  But it did not need to open in order to count the number of tables.  Think of the difference between `SHOW TABLES` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

`table_open_cache` and `table_definition_cache` probably did have all the tables in them when you did the 8 minute query.  Anyway, the values for those `VARIABLES` may have been less than 12,500, implying that there would have been churn.

In the future (probably 5.8), all that info will *probably* be sitting in a single InnoDB table instead of splayed across the OS's file system.  At that point, it will be quite fast.  (Think of how fast a table scan of 12,500 rows can be done, especially if fully cached in RAM.)

Since the information_schema does not have "real" tables, there is no way to add `INDEXes`.

mysqldump does not provide the table size info.  Even if it did, it would be no faster, since it would go through the same, old, mechanism.

60 is a questionably large number of databases; 12K is a large number of tables.  Often this implies a schema design that chooses to create multiple tables instead of putting data into a single table?

Comment: Boy do I agree with that last paragraph! :)